# ask for explanation of sed regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, makefile

I struggle to understand the following two sed regex in a makefile:

```
sw_version:=software/module/1.11.0

sw:= $(shell echo $(sw_version) | sed -e 's:/[^/]*$$::;s:_[^/]*$$::g')
// sw is "software/module"

version:= $(shell echo $(sw_version) | sed -e 's:.*/::g;s/-.*$$//')
// version is "1.11.0"
```

I really appreciate a detailed explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$$` will be substituted to `$` in make files, so the sed expression looks like this:

```
sed -e 's:/[^/]*$::;s:_[^/]*$::g'
```

`s///` is the substitution command. And the delimiter doesn't need to be `/` in your case it's a colon (`:`):

```
s:/[^/]*$::;
s:_[^/]*$::g
```

It works with matching pattern and replacing with replacement:

```
s/pattern/replacement/
```

`;` is a delimiter to use multiply commands in the same call to sed.

So basically this is two substitutions one which replaces `/[^/]*$` another which replaces `_[^/]*$` with nothing.

`[...]` is a character class which will match what ever you stick in there one time. eg: `[abc]` will match either a or b or c. If `^` is in the beginning of the class it will match everything but what is in the class, eg: `[^abc]` will match everything but a and b and c.

`*` will repeat the last pattern zero or more times.

`$` is end of line

Lets apply what we know to the examples above (read bottom up):

```
s:/[^/]*$::;
#^^^^^ ^^ ^^
#||||| || |Delimiter
#||||| || Replace with nothing
#||||| |End of line
#||||| Zero or more times
#||||Literal slash
#|||Match everything but ...
#||Character class
#|Literal slash
#Delimiter used for the substitution command
```

`/[^/]*$` will match literal slash (`/`) followed by everything but a slash zero or more times at end of line.

`_[^/]*$` will match literal underscore (`_`) followed by everything but a slash zero or more times at end of line.

That was the first, the second is left as an exercise.

Comment: so "$" will match only the last literal string "/...", and substitutes with empty. the preceding ones will remain. Also, about the delimiters in sed, what delimiters are allowed? from https://coderwall.com/p/khdkuw/delimiters-in-sed-substitution, it says "sed can use any character as a delimiter, In fact, it will automatically use the character following the s as a delimiter." is it true?

Comment: I think about everything is allowed as delimiter: `echo "123" | sed 's12131'`. `/[^/]*$` will act the same way as dirname. Removing the basename from the input string.